# EventSource .net 4.0 GenerateManifest

Tags: .net-4.0, event-log, system.diagnostics, etw, etw-eventsource

I've been trying to work with ETW in .net 4.0.

I have started using Microsoft EventSource Library 1.0.4-beta (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource)

Here is the code i written for generating events for my application.

```
[EventSource(Name = "Samples-EventSourceDemos-EventSourceLogger")]
public sealed class EventSourceLogger : EventSource
{
    public static EventSourceLogger Log = new EventSourceLogger();

    public static string GetManifest()
    {
        return GenerateManifest(typeof(EventSourceLogger), null);
    }

    [Event(200, Level = Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventLevel.Informational, Task = EventTask.None, Version = 1,
        Opcode = EventOpcode.Info, Keywords = EventKeywords.None, Channel = EventChannel.Admin,
        Message = "Test Message")]
    public void LogEtwInfoEventMessage(string jsonArgs)
    {
        if (!this.IsEnabled()) return;

        this.WriteEvent(200, jsonArgs);
    }

    [Event(400, Level = Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventLevel.Error, Task = EventTask.None, Version = 1,
        Opcode = EventOpcode.Info, Keywords = EventKeywords.None, Channel = EventChannel.Admin, Message = "Test Message")]
    public void LogEtwErrorEventMessage(string jsonArgs)
    {
        if (!this.IsEnabled()) return;

        this.WriteEvent(400, jsonArgs);
    }

    [Event(500, Level = Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventLevel.Warning, Task = EventTask.None, Version = 1,
       Opcode = EventOpcode.Info, Keywords = EventKeywords.None, Channel = EventChannel.Admin, Message = "Test Message")]
    public void LogEtwWarningEventMessage(string jsonArgs)
    {
        if (!this.IsEnabled()) return;

        this.WriteEvent(500, jsonArgs);
    }
}
```

I am not able to generate manifest from listener. Code Below

```
var manifestXml = EventSourceLogger.GetManifest();
```

When I try to call this I get NullReferenceException, Please suggest I am missing any thing. Is it possible to push EventMessage to EventViewer using this version.

As Part of this NuGet Package, I have eventRegister, Install Bat, Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource.targets. I am not really sure how these would help in manifest generate.

If any one have any ideas (or) worked on this, Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

The answer by @magicandre1981 is correct in the sense that it's *not necessary* to generate manifests with newer versions of `.NET` and `EventSource`. (In fact, it's still taking place, but it's just been hidden behind a build event that gets put into your project file when you're installing the [EventSource package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource).)

However, depending on what you're doing, you might still need to generate the manifest manually. Here's one way to do it:

1. Either install the [EventSource package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource) (`Install-Package Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource`) into your project or download and unpack it where you need it
2. Locate the `eventRegister.exe`. (It will most likely be somewhere under folder similar to `packages\Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventRegister.1.1.26\build` relative to the package installation folder)
3. Run the following command:

`eventRegister.exe {path-to-dll-with-your-eventsource-class} {manifest-output-file-prefix}`

After that you'll see two files per each EventSource class that you have in the dll:

- {prefix}{EventSource Name}.etwManifest.dll
- {prefix}{EventSource Name}.etwManifest.man

And those are the ones you can then feed to [wevtutil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/wevtutil):

```
wevtutil.exe 
   im {EtwManifestManFile} 
   /rf:"{EtwManifestDllFile}" 
   /mf:"{EtwManifestDllFile}"
```

Comment: some tools which could be useful described on [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570690/Application-Analysis-with-Event-Tracing-for-Window)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to get the Manifest any longer. You can now directly register the EventSource:

> **Registering your EventSource**
>
> When you install the EventSource NuGet package, the build step
>   previously mentioned generates the following files for each
>   EventSource in your application:
>
> AssemblyName.EventSourceTypeName.etwManifest.man
>
> AssemblyName.EventSourceTypeName.etwManifest.dll.
>
> These files need to be registered with the operating system to enable
>   channel support. To do this you run the following command after the
>   files are in their final deployed location:
>
> wevtutil.exe im EtwManifestManFile /rf:"EtwManifestDllFile"c /mf:"EtwManifestDllFile"

Microsoft explained this in this Blog:

[Announcing the EventSource NuGet Package – Write to the Windows Event Log](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/08/09/announcing-the-eventsource-nuget-package-write-to-the-windows-event-log.aspx)

Comment: I don't see AssemblyName.EventSourceTypeName.etwManifest.man and AssemblyName.EventSourceTypeName.etwManifest.dll generated. Can you give me some light on how manifest can be generated.

Comment: was the eventRegister.exe executed correctly. Also ask this in the MS Blog, this version is just a beta, so there can be still issues.

Comment: Turns out you still need to generate the manifest if you wish to write to the EventViewer using Admin Channel (requires registering the manifest and dll). If you know a better way, please let me know.